# Synchronization-with (SW) order vs synchronization order (SO)

Tags: java, concurrency, java-memory-model

Here: http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2013-November/011954.html
one of the interlocutors says:

> In your reasoning, you do not distinguish 
>   between synchronization order (so) and synchronizes-with order (sw)

I do not see a difference between so and sw as well. Can someone explain it?

---

**EDITED_1:**

> ```
>    read(a, !null) (1)
>       \--po--> vread(a.f, 0)
>                     \---so---> vstore(a.f, 42)
>                                     \---po---> store(a) (4)
> ```

Particullary, I don't undertand the above diagram: `read(a, !null)`(1) means that action read `a` and it is **not-null** whileas an action (4) `store(a)` stored to the `a` variable **after** (1).

So, if we have:

`read(a) --> store_to_a` How `read(a)` can return not null?

---

**EDITED_2**
I don't understand:

> ```
>    vstore(A.f, null) --so--> vread(A.f, null) --so--> vstore(A.f, 42)
> ```

What does it mean `vstore(A.f, null)`. I mean `A.f` is an `int`. So, why the author stores `null` to int? The same with `vread(A.f, null`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Synchronization order is a property of each individual execution, and it's the order of *all* synchronization actions on that execution.

*Synchronizes-with* is a relation partially based on synchronization order (See JLS 17.4.4).

In particular, the post this is responding to assumes there is a *sw* relation between *volatile-read(a.f)* and *volatile-write(a.f)*: there is no such relation, that execution just happens to have those two actions following each other in *synchronization order*, but since there is no *sw* relation, there is no requirement to introduce appropriate fences (and in fact, on some systems you may have a *read-acquire* followed by a *store-release*, which don't synchronize in that order), or, from another point of view, there is no *happens-before*, so there is a data race, the actual behavior is anyone's guess, and it's actually possible for *volatile-read(a.f)* to read 0 without violating anything in JLS 17.

**Answer to Edit 1**

> ```
>    read(a, !null) (1)
>       \--po--> vread(a.f, 0)
>                     \---so---> vstore(a.f, 42)
>                                     \---po---> store(a) (4)
> ```
>
> Particullary, I don't undertand the above diagram: read(a, !null)(1)
>   means that action read a and it is not-null whileas an action (4)
>   store(a) stored to the a variable after (1).

Action 4 happens in a different thread than action 1. Since *f* is not a final field, and *store(a)* is not a volatile write, protected by a monitor, ... there is nothing forcing the subscribing thread to see *vstore(a.f, 42)* and *store(a)* in that order. e.g. *store(a)* can be forwarded to another CPU before *vstore(a.f, 42)*.

Put another way, the diagram is misleading, and should better be decomposed into:

```
Synchronization Order:
    vread(a.f, 0) ---so---> vstore(a.f, 42)
Program Order in publishing thread:
    vstore(a.f, 42) ---po---> store(a)
Program Order in subscribing thread:
    read(a, !null) ---po---> vread(a.f, 0)
```

It would make sense to use a single diagram only if the program was *race-free*, which would imply that all executions would need to appear to be *sequentially-consistent*, which looks like a simple interleaving of threads. In the absence of DRF-SC (*data race freedom - sequentially consistent*) behaviour, things are not so simple. Even then, I would recommend a diagram with separate threads, as below:

```
Publishing thread       Subscribing thread

                             read(a, !null)
                                  |
                                  po
                                  |
                                  v
                            vread(a.f, 0)
                          /     
                         so     
                        /       
                       v       
    vstore(a.f, 42)
       |
       po
       |
       v
    store(a)
```

The *happens-before* order is composed solely of the *intra-thread* *program-order* of the two threads, and no *inter-thread* *synchronizes-with* ordering at all. In particular, there is no *happens-before* relation between *vread(a.f, 0)* and *vstore(a.f, 42)*, so there is a data race, and not all executions of the program need to appear to be *sequentially-consistent*.

**Answer to Edit 2**

> What does it mean vstore(A.f, null). I mean A.f is an int. So, why the
>   author stores null to int? The same with vread(A.f, null)

In this case, the author used *null* to represent the default value of the field. It's just notation, don't read too much into it.

Comment: thanks for your answer. If you can, please read my edited post and try to clear my doubts.

Comment: You are great, man :). Thanks a lot for your explanation. 
"The happens-before order is composed solely of the intra-thread program-order of the two threads, and **no** inter-thread synchronizes-with ordering at all. "
Why no? If there is no inter-thread sw relation how it can be happens before?

Comment: So, the key of my problem was:
`op1, op2, op3, .. , vstore, op6` And `op6` can be reordered with `op1`, or `op2`, or `vstore` etc., but vstore cannot be reordered with `op1, op2, op3,`, yes?